# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, viewer

I have deployed a report viewer control on a .Net application hosted on a 2003 server. When I call any report (all of which work on the SSRS server and via a browser) I get the following error in the logs.

**System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.**

The rest of the exception is below:

```
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport2(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.<>c__DisplayClass2.<LoadReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetParameters()
   at XXXXXXXX.Web.Reports.ReportViewer_SSRS.SetParameters(NameValueCollection qsVars)
   at XXXXXXXX.Web.Reports.ReportViewer_SSRS.RetrieveAndDisplayReport()
```

I've googled this quite heavily and am still none the wiser. The same code can connect to different SSRS environments o.k on other boxes. The firewall between the hosting .Net server and the ssrs server is open (As I said I can see the report when I pop the address in a browser) but this happens when it is called via the report viewer control. The log on credentials that the SSRS datasource uses also work and the Report viewer uses a service account to connect to the SSRS box.

If anyone has ever came across this error and has a few minutes to write a reply I'd really appreciate any advice or ideas to trouble shoot. Unfortunately I dont have direct access to the Server hosting the SSRS as it's another department but I can beg them for access for a short time.

Regards
Vince

Comment: You should format your error to make it easier to read. Possibly only including the parts that are useful. You may also want to add any relevant code that could be helpful for us to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered this and thought I should write what was causing this so it may help someone else in the future:

The ICT department had a look at the server in question and stated that
there was a part of SSL config in registry that was interfering somehow with SSL communication. I dont have the reputation to show the registry screen shot I was sent unfortunately

Regards